# Getting an item from the firebase database and update it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have below structure in my firebase database and i will be having edit button beside each item in my html page to update the item info. I am confused to achieve this requirement as i am new to firebase

```
const bookref = admin.database().ref(); //added this line to access ref

app.get('/update',(req,res) => { //code to update

    const id = req.query.id;
    console.log('query id',id);
    bookref.child('books').orderByChild(id).on('value',(snapshot) =>{

        var val = snapshot.val();
        var val2 = JSON.stringify(val);
        //console.log('test',val2)
        res.render('update',{val2})
    })

    //res.render('update')
})
```

even after trying this code, I am getting null value from firebase.

This is the link to my firebase structure:

[image: firebase structure]

Answer (score 0):

Your code accesses the Firebase Realtime Database, but your screenshot is of Cloud Firestore.

While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and have separate APIs. To fix the error, you will either have to use the Cloud Firestore API, or look for your data in the Realtime Database.

To learn more about the two databases, see the Firebase documentation on [choosing a database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore).

Comment: i want to upload images to my website using cloud firestore. i'm unable to find the proper documentation to do that. can you please help me.

Comment: The code you shared in your question has nothing to do with uploading images, so that use-case seems unrelated to this question.